# Get filtered rows from a table and its pivot table using eloquent in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models Base_voter and Custom_list

## Custom_list.php

```
public function base_voters()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Base_voter', 'custom_pivot_base', 'custom_list_id', 'base_voter_id');
}
```

## Base_voter

```
public function custom_lists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Custom_list', 'custom_pivot_base', 'custom_list_id', 'base_voter_id');
}
```

There is pivot table custom_pivot_base with two columns

`custom_list_id, base_voter_id`

Now, I need to retrieve base_voter lists whose customer_list_id = 1 and street = $street, where city = $city. These address and city column are in base_voters table. How can I do this with eloquent in laravel

Comment: It should be a `belongsToMany` relationship on both models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your relationship in `Custom_list` Model

```
public function base_voters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Base_voter', 'custom_pivot_base', 'custom_list_id', 'base_voter_id');
}
```

Also change your relationship in `Base_voter` Model

```
public function custom_lists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Custom_list', 'custom_pivot_base', 'base_voter_id', 'custom_list_id');
}
```

You need to fetch `base_voter` lists  for `customer_list_id = 1` that means fetch  `customer_list` by id 1 and then fetch its related `base_voters`. Like this

```
$customList = Custom_list::with(['base_voters' => function($query) use ($city, $gender){  

                    $query->where('city',$city)->where('gender', $gender);

              }])->find(1);
```

Now you can print it like this

```
print_r($customList->base_voters);
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base_voter.custom_pivot_base' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `base_voter` where `base_voter`.`custom_pivot_base` is null and `base_voter`.`custom_pivot_base` is not null and `base_voter`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: do you have `custom_pivot_base` table with 'custom_list_id' and 'base_voter_id` fields ? and the relationships defined ?

Comment: updated answer, check it. you should have belongsToMany in both Models

Comment: Well, it works, now how can I make filter such as gender = $gender, city = $city

Comment: in which table these fields are ?

Comment: Yeah, am too from kathmandu. I have accepted your answer but there is a syntax error you are missing curly bracket to close. Please, add it there.

Comment: fixed it, happy to help you.

Answer (score -1):

What u are looking for is "hasManyThrough" relationship.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Please go through this documentation and define the relationship between your models.